# finder indexing

Tags: finder, monterey, indexing

I recently added a text file to an exiting folder. To check I could use Finder to find the file, I searched for some unique text within the file only to find Finder could not find the file. If this is a re-indexing issue, how long do I wait for the search to be successful ? Is there something wrong with indexing ?

Comment: Where is the file, specifically? Is it in a known indexed area? Indexing should be almost instantaneous for a small-ish file. I copied an existing file from one drive to another, then searched a keyword. Found immediately. I then copy/pasted a lot more text into it & added one fairly unique word, saved them immediately searched that word. Again found straight away.

Comment: @ Tetsujin, the file is in a folder that sits on the desktop and is an html file. I now discover the nature of the problem has changed. Finder finds the file for a given text string within it, but not any text string :-(